# How can i implement open on maps - google maps

Tags: ios, swift

I’ve been looking for a way to implement these two options on swift when user clicks on a button but i didn’t find a way to implement this. Does anyone knows how or if anyone have a tutorial for this.
[image: Options Pic]

Comment: show us what you have tried so far...

Comment: I've already designed the button to take user to the map without asking. i want to implement this so user can choose

Answer (score 0):

Second image is nothing but [UIAlertController](https://medium.com/swift-india/uialertcontroller-in-swift-22f3c5b1dd68).

When click on those follow url pattern to open in maps [check this for apple/ google map](https://medium.com/swift-productions/launch-google-to-show-route-swift-580aca80cf88)

For Waze, follow below pattern

```
waze://?ll=<lat>,<lon>&navigate=yes
```